# AGC (automatic gain control) circuit for brushless phase measurement?

Tags: signal, brushless-dc-motor, back-emf, linearity, automatic-gain-control

**Intro:** I am projecting a Brushless motor driver which relevant specs here are basically: use with 6v to 60v.
To make it work the circuit's microcontroller needs to analyze the signal that comes from the motor phases through ADC - which can not exceed 3.3v.

The phase maximum voltage is ideally equal to the power voltage and looks like the wave form shown bellow, for the three wires:
[image]

So that, if it uses a simple resistive divider to measure each phase:

- when the power is 60v, the phase value at the ADC input must be bellow 3.3v.
- When the power is 6v (10x lower than 60 volts), at the ADC input it will be 3.3v divided by 10, i.e., 0.33v.

**The Problem:** Notice that using resistors simply the precision was lost by 10x (more than 3 bits!). This can cause instability at lower voltages and worse control, compared to 60v on power supply.

**Solutions?** I was thinking about using a AGC to adjust the signal to the ADC input based on the power supply voltage. No meter what voltage on the power supply, the ADC should catch a 0-to-3.3v signal linearly similar to the phase signal. What AGC chip you guys recommend? What else could be a possible simpler solution?

Comment: Realistically people don't build systems that work over such a wide voltage range.  You'd likely to encounter many other practical problems in trying to get a design which can support high voltage to work at only 6 volts.  That said, you're probably overestimating the amount of "analysis" needed - likely what you need is to find the zero crossings, then use that to discipline a *model* of the rotor position.  So you can probably use some sort of clipping scheme.  You might look at schematics for *actual* hobby etc ESC's.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisStratton, usually it's only the zero crossings of the BEMF waveform that you care about, so why not just use a clamp to prevent the waveform from exceeding some safe voltage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton , it is a project to enable some other methods to get a precise control for the motor. Some methods use integration, which could get really wrong if the ADC precision is wasted. What do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest you think more about the problem: at high RPM, a model of rotor position fed only by the zero crossings is ample.  At low RPM, your *actual* back EMF in the sense of kv * rpm will also be low even if the *available* supply voltage is high.  But I continue to think your desired power supply range is unreasonably wide to try to support in a single selection of components.